# Visual Studio Code javaFX set up

Tags: java, javafx, visual-studio-code

[image: screenshot of my vs code]

So I'm trying to set up javafx in my vs code but the "Referenced Libraries" does not show up under "Java Projects" if the project already exists. Does anyone know why? Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's indeed **Referenced Libraries** for No Tools project. When it comes to gradle, the referenced libraries are shown as **dependencies**, which are declared in `build.gradle`. You may add the needed dependencies in the

```
dependencies{
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    ....    
}
```

About gradle dependency, please view the guide [Working with Dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html).

Comment: Are the "...." meant to be a place holder for something I'm meant to put in?

Comment: Yes, put the dependencies you will use in your project.